# Couldn't start Xtightvnc trying default font path - VNCServer

Tags: xfce, vnc, tightvncserver

I installed VNC, using

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies tightvncserver
```

But I can't start it, when I enter

```
vncserver
```

I'm getting error message as

```
Couldn't start Xtightvnc; trying default font path.
Please set correct fontPath in the vncserver script.
Couldn't start Xtightvnc process.

15/07/15 18:59:34 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.9
15/07/15 18:59:34 Copyright (C) 2000-2007 TightVNC Group
15/07/15 18:59:34 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
15/07/15 18:59:34 All Rights Reserved.
15/07/15 18:59:34 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
15/07/15 18:59:34 Desktop name 'X' (vultr.guest:1)
15/07/15 18:59:34 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
15/07/15 18:59:34 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring

Fatal server error:
could not open default font 'fixed'
```

I have solved one issue by adding hostname in hosts file. But still having other errors, please help.

Comment: That's odd, at least some of those font directories should have been created as part of the `xfonts-base` package, which is recommended for `tightvncserver`: did you install it with `--no-install-recommends`?

Comment: No, I was installed using sudo    apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies tightvncserver

Comment: still no solutions found for this problem. Already re-installed server few times, but still stuck in this exception. Please help me..

Comment: `sudo apt-get install xfonts-base` and `sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi` and `sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi` fixes font issues.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Atlast after tried many solutions and fixes I fixed this issue. I almost give up, but fixed now.

Problem 1: `Couldn't start Xtightvnc process.`

Solution: check your hostname, and /etc/hosts make sure both are same. To edit those files, use the commands.

```
nano /etc/hostname
nano /etc/hosts
hostname
```

Problem 2:

```
Couldn't start Xtightvnc; trying default font path.
Please set correct fontPath in the vncserver script.
Couldn't start Xtightvnc process.
```

Solution: The x11 fonts are missing, I don't know why the dependency packages are not installed. Try to find folder

```
ls /usr/share/fonts/X11/
```

if it is not found, then try to install xfonts base

```
apt-get install  xfonts-base
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, sadly.

Comment: Installing xfonts-base worked for me when setting up a new Ubuntu server in the Vultr cloud service. Thanks.

Comment: Set DPI that its font is already existed in `/usr/share/fonts/X11/`

Comment: Nothing here works.

Comment: Still getting same message. Ubuntu 20.04 fresh server install

Comment: It worked perfectly -thank you !

Answer (score 8):

Maybe to help others - check the logs!

I was running

```
vncserver -geometty 1200x900 -alwaysshared -localhost -compatiblekbd :1
```

I experienced the same message

```
Couldn't start Xtightvnc; trying default font path.
Please set correct fontPath in the vncserver script.
Couldn't start Xtightvnc process.

# ... list of tightvnc options
```

My solution was to check the log

```
cat ~/.vnc/hostname:display.log | less
```

which indicated a mispelled option (-geometty) - I missed the message in stdout >_<; it was sandwiched between other things.

Comment: This answer saved me! Thank's for saying what was mispelled (geometty): that remembered me that I insterted a comment in the geometry line of config: `geometry 848x480   # good for mobile`, what is not permitted there. But the error messages were about fonts! Hard to associate fonts with geometry!

Comment: just foundout using neither `-geometry=1920x1080` is wrong but using space instead of `=`. it's confusing because the GNU argument syntax is either using long full word with equal or using shorthand with space, not long full word with space.
I missed it because the output complaints about fonts

Answer (score 6):

On Kubuntu 14.04 I had the same error with tightvnc server, and while debugging switched to vnc4server, which had the same error. I resolved it in vnc4 by setting the font path.

I got the font path by running

```
xset q
```

and getting the value of "Font Path:". I then used this as the value for the "-fp" option. E.g.

```
vncserver -fp "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins"
```

which seems to just pass it through to the underlying Xvnc4 server invocation.

Comment: Running the vncserver command with the -fp option (I ran the above command except without the build-ins part at the end because I didn't have that directory) made the error go away for me. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me too, ty.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as extra fonts were not installed and I had issue installing extra packages.
Solved it by adding DNS servers.
I followed this tip.

To add a dns server w/o changing your permanent setup, just add the entries to /etc/resolv.conf. This should reset when you reboot. The below will use the google dns servers. (this only lasts until next reboot)

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Adding it permanently is a different animal. I would edit /etc/network/interfaces and under the wlan0 block add the following line:

dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

Then do an
apt-get update 
then run any installs like 
apt-get install  xfonts-base

Answer (score 0):

Some distros lack base font package. Try to download `6x13-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz` from https://github.com/BlackArch/blackarch-iso/blob/master/live-iso/airootfs/usr/share/fonts/misc/ and put this file to `/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the old .pid and .log files from ~/.vnc  This errors seems to be pretty generic for any I can't read any file for some reason.  Messing with fonts probably won't help you.

This worked for me on 16.04 and 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

```
Fatal server error:
could not open default font 'fixed'
```

Make sure that in `/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/` there are:

- `fonts.alias` file with `fixed <fontname>` string
- `fonts.dir` file with the corresponding `<filename> <fontname>` string
- a font file with that filename.

Answer (score 0):

Since literally none of the above worked for me, the real answer to this problem is to use the following command when using Ubuntu 20.04:

```
vncserver -rfbport 5901 -fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/ -co /etc/X11/rgb -depth 24 -geometry 1920x1080 -localhost
```

That means if you set it up as a service, you'll need to edit the ExecStart line as well to include these options.