# Missing icons with Xfce on Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04, icons, xfce, vnc

I use Ubuntu with VNC connection from Windows. I see most of the icons as follows:

[image: ubuntu icons]

System information:

```
Linux vps568 4.15.0-52-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 4 22:49:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `xfconf-query -c xsettings -lv` command:

```
/Gtk/ButtonImages               true
/Gtk/CanChangeAccels            false
/Gtk/ColorPalette               black:white:gray50:red:purple:blue:light blue:geen:yellow:orange:lavender:brown:goldenrod4:dodger blue:pink:light green:gray10gray30:gray75:gray90
/Gtk/CursorThemeName
/Gtk/CursorThemeSize            0
/Gtk/DecorationLayout           menu:minimize,maximize,close
/Gtk/FontName                   Sans 10
/Gtk/IconSizes
/Gtk/KeyThemeName
/Gtk/MenuBarAccel               F10
/Gtk/MenuImages                 true
/Gtk/MonospaceFontName          Monospace 10
/Gtk/ToolbarIconSize            3
/Gtk/ToolbarStyle               icons
/Net/CursorBlink                true
/Net/CursorBlinkTime            1200
/Net/DndDragThreshold           8
/Net/DoubleClickDistance        5
/Net/DoubleClickTime            400
/Net/EnableEventSounds          false
/Net/EnableInputFeedbackSounds  false
/Net/IconThemeName              elementary-xfce-dark
/Net/SoundThemeName             default
/Net/ThemeName                  Greybird
/Xft/Antialias                  -1
/Xft/Hinting                    -1
/Xft/HintStyle                  hintnone
/Xft/RGBA                       none
```

I already tried this command too, but hasn't any visible changes:

```
xfdesktop --replace
```

Comment: dpkg -l | grep greybird-gtk-theme

Comment: `ii  greybird-gtk-theme                    3.22.8-1                                all          grey GTK+ theme from the Shimmer Project`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the packages are missing. probably from using the server version instead of the desktop

I've got the same problem.

I ended up installing gnome first time, `xfce` was still there after.

```
sudo tasksel
```

pick a package, I went with `xubuntu minimal,` didn't get come with browser it seems, so going with the full `xubuntu` desktop.  You think that should do what I need, still messing with it.

Also needed fonts, not sure if this is the same as the font package in tasksel

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-base and sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi and sudo apt-get install xfonts-75dpi fixes font issues. – gies0r Dec 10 '19 at 19:22
```

[Couldn't start Xtightvnc trying default font path - VNCServer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648819/couldnt-start-xtightvnc-trying-default-font-path-vncserver#comment2001805_648819)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the package `xubuntu-icon-theme` is installed. Open a **Terminal** and type:

```
dpkg -i | grep  xubuntu-icon-theme
```

If, it's not installed, type the following:

```
sudo apt install xubuntu-icon-theme
```

Now, update the `icon-cache`:

```
sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce \
/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce-dark /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce-darker \
/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce-darkest
```

Normaly, after installating a Theme it is triggered from postinst script.

```
cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/xubuntu-icon-theme.postinst | grep update-icon-caches
```

Gived the following output

```
if which update-icon-caches >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce-dark /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce-darker /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce-darkest
```

Comment: I used these commands and also restarted system, but still has the same issues.

Comment: I suspect that. It must be related to VNC. I was hopping this error is fixed. I only found older threads. Sorry not my field.

Comment: @user966203 update your post to include a link to the source from which you took this information.

Comment: @user966203 : Sorry, but it doesn't help. Could you please modify your answer?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware) is the Ubuntu wiki article about package management. Themes are usually available as packages.

To install the missing icon themes from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xubuntu-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme tango-icon-theme
```

If you have a message error like the following:

> (meld:1021): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'document-new'
> for stock: Icon 'document-new' not present in theme elementary-xfce

you can fix this error message with:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```

(This information is took from ToZ user in https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12702)